# C# - calling the paint event handler

Tags: c#, event-handling

I want to call my paint event when i click a button. I have this:

```
private void btnDrawMap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rows = Convert.ToInt32(this.numRows);
            cols = Convert.ToInt32(this.numCols);


            defineCellWallsList();
            defineCellPositionsList();
            pictureBox1_Paint_1;
        }
```

I don't think you can call it in this way. All `pictureBox1_Paint_1` does is:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            myGameForm.drawMap(e, mapCellWallList, mapCellPositionList);
        }
```

So if i can call `myGameForm.drawMap` instead, that would be fine. Which is:

```
public void drawMap(PaintEventArgs e, List<List<int>> walls, List<List<int>> positions)
        {
            // Create a local version of the graphics object for the PictureBox.
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            // Loop through mapCellArray.
            for (int i = 0; i < walls.Count; i++)
            {
                int[] mapData = getMapData(i, walls, positions);
                int column = mapData[0];
                int row = mapData[1];
                int right = mapData[2];
                int bottom = mapData[3];

                g.DrawLine(setPen(right), column + squareSize, row, column + squareSize, row + squareSize);
                g.DrawLine(setPen(bottom), column + squareSize, row + squareSize, column, row + squareSize);
            }
            drawMapEdges(e, walls, positions);
        }
```

It requires a `paintEventArg` and the `btnDrawMap_Click` requires an eventArg, so i changed the `btnDrawMap_Click` eventArg parameter to paintEventArg, however it has an error stating that `btnDrawMap_Click` has not overloaded method that takes an eventHandler.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `Invalidate()`, which forces the `PictureBox` to redraw itself, thereby calling your `Paint` event:

```
pictureBox1.Invalidate();
```